# Keep getting "'setActiveSheet' of null"

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a problem with one of my codes that is giving me a really hard time. I have essentially put together a few different scripts I have used before to build this one, but the second half of it is not working.

I am able to get ti to pull the CSV from an email and create a new spreadsheet and sheet and name them correctly, but when I get to the part of formatting is where I have issues.

I would like it so that after it has created the new sheet and deleted "Sheet1" to set the new sheet to active so I am able to then format the sheet with the second half of the script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function ImportPropertyPerformance() {
  

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('* Performance');

let date = new Date( new Date().getTime());
let date_mmddyyyy = (date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getDate()+"/"+date.getFullYear();
let thismonth = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date_mmddyyyy),"GMT-8","MMMM")
 
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  Logger.log('Message: ' + message);

  
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
  Logger.log('Attachment: ' + attachment.getContentType());

 
  if (attachment.getContentType() === 'text/csv') {


    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(thismonth + " Performance");
    Logger.log('ss: ' + ss);
    
    
    sheet = ss.insertSheet();
    sheet.setName(thismonth);
    Logger.log('sheet: ' + sheet);

   
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString("UTF-8"), ",");
    Logger.log('Found a CSV file');

    
    sheet.clearContents();

    
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length,     csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

   
var deletesheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
ss.deleteSheet(deletesheet);


  }
  



var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].moveToTrash();
    
  };

{
  var newsheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  newsheet.setActiveSheet(newsheet.getSheets()[0]);

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C:C').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('"$"#,##0.00');
  spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('"$"#,##0.00');
  spreadsheet.getRange('G:G').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('"$"#,##0.00');
  spreadsheet.getRange('H:H').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('"$"#,##0.00');

  spreadsheet.getRange('1:1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setFrozenRows(1);



  spreadsheet.getRange('I3').activate()
  .setFormula('=if(B3>1,IF(((C3+D3)*F3)<100,100,ROUND((C3+D3)*F3,2)),"")');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('I3:I1000'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('I3:I1000').activate();



  spreadsheet.getRange('I:I').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());




  spreadsheet.getRange('J3').activate()
  .setFormula('=ifs(B3="","",F3="Flat Fee","Flat Fee Management?",AND(C3<E3,C3>1),"Incorrect ?")');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('J3:J1000'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('J3:J1000').activate();

  spreadsheet.getRange('J:J').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setColumnWidth(10, 225);
  spreadsheet.getRange('K:K').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setColumnWidth(11, 550);
  spreadsheet.getRange('K1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Notes');
  spreadsheet.getRange('J1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Finding');
   
spreadsheet.getRange('J:J').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J:J').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J1').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(10, criteria);


}




};
```

Comment: Please post the exact error and identify the exact line that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Change this `spreadsheet.getRange('C:C').activate(); spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('"$"#,##0.00');`

to this:  `spreadsheet.getRange('C:C').setNumberFormat('"$"#,##0.00');`

It might be good to specify the sheet as well

Comment: Sorry I tried to edit it, but apparent ran out of time. My goal is to specify the exact sheet.  I am getting the error on line 58. "newsheet.setActiveSheet(newsheet.getSheets()[0]);" In one iteration I had, it had no issue with .getrange() but then had an issue with .getactivesheet() in line 71 (spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setFrozenRows(1);)

Comment: Which is line 58?

Comment: newsheet.setActiveSheet(newsheet.getSheets()[0]);